# Каретка с помощью css

Tags: html, css3

Я хочу поменять вид каретки с "палочки" на "прямоугольник" как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

`caret-shape` и `caret-color` вам в помощь

https://hcdev.ru/css/caret-color/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/caret-shape/

```css
.other {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    
    font-size: 30px;
    
    caret: red;
    caret-shape: block;
}

но поддерживается это не у всех :)
```

```html
<input class = 'other'>
```

Comment: Почему то не работает в Google но как тогда он подключается в терминале? Он отображается как обычный курсор